# Copy multiple selected cells data in excell and make string and show in box?

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I want to copy the excell sheet selected cell data and want to view them in output summary box  here i was trying the  code that copy only a data of specific row

```
Public Sub Conclusion()
  Dim myVariable As String
  myVariable = Selection.Value
  OutputForm.SummaryBox = myVariable
  OutputForm.Show
End Sub
```

now can you please help me with code that copy the selected multiple row data and make string and view in my summary box

Answer (score 0):

Here I have done the code myself

```
Public Sub Conclusion()

  Dim r As Range
  For Each r In Selection.Rows
      OutputForm.SummaryBox = OutputForm.SummaryBox & " " & Cells(r.Row, 4).Value  
  Next r
  OutputForm.Show

End Sub
```